# How to redirect to a page after the form is submitted

Tags: plugins, php, forms

I am New to Wordpress.I am creating a Plugin Where I have to import a csv File to database.Uploaded and Entered data Successfully.But my Problem is once the file gets uploaded it shows a blank page with the success Message.How can I redirect to the same Page with success or error Message please help..Thanks in Advance..
Here is my code

```
$admin_services =   add_menu_page('Fee Schedule','Fee Schedule','administrator','pd-services','pd_services');
<?php
function pd_services(){
if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['admin_service_csv_upload']))          {
        if(get_file_extension($_FILES["service_upload_csv"]["name"])!= 'csv')
        {
            $error[] = 'Only CSV files accepted!';
        }
    if (!$error){
        $tot = 0;
        $handle = fopen($_FILES["service_upload_csv"]["tmp_name"], "r");
            //echo $file   =  $_FILES["service_upload_csv"]["tmp_name"];
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                for ($c=0; $c < 1; $c++) {
                    //only run if the first column if not equal to firstname
                    if($data[0] !='Department Name'){
                        $insert_csv_query = "INSERT INTO wp_services(
                                    dept_name,
                                    inc_10_codes,
                                    description,
                                    uc_fee
                                                )VALUES(
                                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."',
                                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."',
                                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[2])."',
                                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[3])."'
                                    )";
                            $insert_csv_query;
                        $inserted = $wpdb->query($insert_csv_query);
                        }

                    echo $tot++;
            }
    }
fclose($handle);
$content.= "<div class='success' id='message'> CSV File Imported, $tot records added         </div>";
}
} else {
?>
<div class="wrap">
    <form name="csvupload" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="uploadcsv">Upload Services from CSV</label></th>
                <td><input type = "file" name="service_upload_csv" id="upload_csv_id" aria-required="true"></td>
            </tr>
            <td>
            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" class="button-primary" name="admin_service_csv_upload" value="<?php _e('Save Changes')?>" />
            </p>
        </td>
        </table>
    </form>
    <?php echo $content ?>
</div>
<?php
}
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the else statement so that user will see the message and will be able to upload csv again or you can redirect using

`echo '<script>windows.location.href="' . $url . '"</script>';
die;`

Edit

```
$admin_services = add_menu_page( 'Fee Schedule', 'Fee Schedule', 'administrator', 'pd-  services', 'pd_services' );
function pd_services() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
    <form name="csvupload" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="uploadcsv">Upload Services from CSV</label></th>
                <td><input type="file" name="service_upload_csv" id="upload_csv_id" aria-required="true"></td>
            </tr>
            <td>
                <p class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" class="button-primary" name="admin_service_csv_upload"
                           value="<?php _e( 'Save Changes' ) ?>"/>
                </p>
            </td>
        </table>
    </form>
    <?php echo $content ?>
</div>
```

```
function process_pd_services_upload() {
if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset( $_POST['admin_service_csv_upload'] ) ) {
    if ( get_file_extension( $_FILES["service_upload_csv"]["name"] ) != 'csv' ) {
        $error[] = 'Only CSV files accepted!';
    }
    if ( ! $error ) {
        $tot    = 0;
        $handle = fopen( $_FILES["service_upload_csv"]["tmp_name"], "r" );
        //echo $file   =  $_FILES["service_upload_csv"]["tmp_name"];
        while ( ( $data = fgetcsv( $handle, 1000, "," ) ) !== false ) {
            for ( $c = 0; $c < 1; $c ++ ) {
                //only run if the first column if not equal to firstname
                if ( $data[0] != 'Department Name' ) {
                    $insert_csv_query = "INSERT INTO wp_services(
                                dept_name,
                                inc_10_codes,
                                description,
                                uc_fee
                                            )VALUES(
                                '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $data[0] ) . "',
                                '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $data[1] ) . "',
                                '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $data[2] ) . "',
                                '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $data[3] ) . "'
                                )";
                    $insert_csv_query;
                    $inserted = $wpdb->query( $insert_csv_query );
                }

                echo $tot ++;
            }
        }
        fclose( $handle );
        $_SESSION['pd_services_total_import'] = $tot;
        wp_safe_redirect( admin_url( 'your admin url here' ) );
    }
 }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'process_pd_services_upload' );
```

In the redirected page you can display message from the `$_SESSION['pd_services_total_import']` an then `unset( $_SESSION['pd_services_total_import'] )`

Comment: Thanks for your response @sabarnix, I have doubt here Is there any problem in submitting a form in the same page?

Comment: I have never faced any issue, I have done it many times

Comment: Thanks @sabarnix.Will it makes a duplitae row if the user press f5?

Comment: Yes it will. In order to avoid that you you can either use the above code or do the for submit checking in `wp` hook and redirect using wp_safe_redirect()

Comment: can you suggest me any examples please @sabarnix

Comment: added the example code in answer